# what's is the best UI tool at client side for Sybase 12.x?

Tags: database, sap-ase

MS SQL Server have a very good UI tool SQL Server Management Studio, it is stable and is able to populate large amount of data.

but Sybase UI tool for ISQL Sybase Central is not stable, many bug/error. Inteactive SQL has very bad performance when try to load large amount of data or access a large table(for example, a table exceed 10G data).

Any similar UI tool like SSMS for MSSQL Server for Sybase?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Embarcadero DB Artisan (or DB Power Studio](http://www.embarcadero.com/products/db-powerstudio-for-sybase)) and [Bradmark Surveillance](http://www.bradmark.com/site/products/sybase/surveillancedb/surveillancedb.html) are the tools I hear about the most.

I have seen DB Artisan in action, and it looks like a fairly well built tool.  I can't speak to either authoritatively as I use the CLI.

Answer (score 0):

Toad for Sybase is a fantastic tool, especially if you have previous experience with Toad for Oracle.

Surprise surprise, Toad for Sybase is free as well!